# ng-if is always evaluated to true inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm looping on an array of objects and I want to display some stuff depending on the value of a field for each item in the array. For this, I have a ng-repeat iterating through my array, and an ng-if evaluating if my current item value is appropriated.

For some reason the ng-if seems to always be evaluated to true (or not evaluated at all?)

**edit.html**

```
<div data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>

  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="legalRemedy in legalRemedies">
      <div ng-if="legalRemedy.erased === false">
        Only valid stuff here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**controller.js**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.bulletin.legalRemedies = [{
    "erased": true // invalid stuff
  }];

});
```

Here's the jsfiddle (no data should be displayed as the erased property is true)
https://jsfiddle.net/vtcLpzmx/2/

It's probably pretty dumb but I cannot find why and it's killing me

Comment: Your jsFiddle are not 'executed' as an angular app, try to add a {{ 1+2 }} expression somwhere and observe it is not displayed as 3 but  as {{ 1+2 }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. just in your jsfiddle I think you have missed to add angular script. so that it doesn't consider that fiddle as angular application.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bulletin = {};
  $scope.bulletin.legalRemedies = [{"erased" : true}]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>

  <div>
  
    <div ng-repeat="legalRemedy in bulletin.legalRemedies">
      <div ng-if="!legalRemedy.erased">
        Only valid stuff here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.bulletin.legalRemedies is causing error because $scope.bulletin is undefined. first you need to declare $scope.bulletin to an object.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div data-ng-app='myApp' data-ng-controller='myCtrl'>
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="legalRemedy in bulletin.legalRemedies">
      <div ng-if="!legalRemedy.erased">
        Only valid stuff here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bulletin = {
    legalRemedies : [{
      "erased": true // invalid stuff
    }
    ]
  }

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try below solution. changed `$scope.bulletin` variable.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.bulletin = { legalRemedies : [{
    "erased": true // invalid stuff
  },{
    "erased": false 
  }] };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="legalRemedy in bulletin.legalRemedies">
      {{$index}} - {{ legalRemedy }}
      <div ng-if="!legalRemedy.erased">
        Only valid stuff here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
    
    
</div>
```